# program deadlock involving __unregister_atfork & TCMalloc

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, fork, tcmalloc

Consider the following C++ program. I expect that the first thread to invoke `exit` will terminate the program. This is what happens when I compile it with `g++ -g test.cxx -lpthread`. However, when I link against TCMalloc (`g++ -g test.cxx -lpthread -ltcmalloc`), it hangs. **Why?**

Examination of the stack frames suggests that the first thread to invoke `exit` is stuck in `__unregister_atfork` waiting on some sort of reference-counted variable to reach 0. Since it previously acquired the mutex, all other threads become deadlocked. My guess is that there is some sort of interaction betweek tcmalloc's atfork handlers and my code.

Tested on CentOS 6.4 with gperftools 2.0.

```
$ cat test.cxx
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

static pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

static void* task(void*) {
    if (fork() == 0)
        return NULL;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << getpid() << endl;

    pthread_t t;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        pthread_create(&t, NULL, task, NULL);
    }

    sleep(9999);
}

$ g++ -g test.cxx -lpthread && $ ./a.out 
19515

$ g++ -g test.cxx -lpthread -ltcmalloc && ./a.out                             
24252
<<< process hangs indefinitely >>>
^C

$ pstack 24252
Thread 101 (Thread 0x7ffaabdf7700 (LWP 24253)):
#0  0x000000328c4f84c4 in __unregister_atfork () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffaac02d2c6 in __do_global_dtors_aux () from /usr/lib64/libtcmalloc.so.4
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Thread 100 (Thread 0x7ffaab3f6700 (LWP 24254)):
#0  0x000000328cc0e054 in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x000000328cc09388 in _L_lock_854 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x000000328cc09257 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x0000000000400abf in task(void*) ()
#4  0x000000328cc07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x000000328c4e894d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
<<< the other 98 threads are also deadlocked >>>
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7ffaabdf9740 (LWP 24252)):
#0  0x000000328c4acbcd in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000328c4aca40 in sleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000400b33 in main ()
```

**EDIT:** I think the problem might be that `exit` is not thread-safe. According to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_01), `exit` is thread-safe. However, the [glibc documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Normal-Termination.html) states that `exit` is *not* thread-safe.

Comment: This is very interesting indeed. Same issue happens with jemalloc btw. But my attempt to reproduce this without tcmalloc or jemalloc was unsuccessful. Also commenting out pthread_atfork call from inside tcmalloc "fixed" the problem.