# child process stuck in fork() when parent calls exit(0)

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, daemon

**Background:**

My program *test.c* is creating a daemon process.

*Code snippet from test.c which creates a daemon process.*

```
sigset_t set;
pid_t   pid;
if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
{
    printf("Did not create the daemon process\n");
    exit(1);
}
else if (pid != 0)
{
    exit(0);
}
setsid();
chdir("/");
closefiles();
...
```

I use a rc script to start my program test.c.

**Problem:**

On rare occasions I see that the script hangs and the test.c daemon is hung in the fork() system call.

*Backtrace of the process seen in gdb.*

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f6743dd5859 in __unregister_atfork () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f6744f215f3 in __do_global_dtors_aux () from <an internal library>
#2  0x00007ffd358e29b0 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007f674566786a in _dl_fini () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

I think this could be due to race condition. I could understand that the parent process exited even before the fork() system call in child completed execution, this has caused some sort of deadlock. It seems like this happens in a very small time window, because adding a printf() statement before exit(0) lead to successful execution of the script and the daemon process.

*This code works!*

```
sigset_t set;
pid_t   pid;
if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
{
    printf("Did not create the daemon process\n");
    exit(1);
}
else if (pid != 0)
{
    printf("Parent process about to exit\n");
    exit(0);
}
printf("Started child process\n");
setsid();
chdir("/");
...
```

**What I want to understand:**

1. How do I debug this problem to understand why exit() caused the fork() to hang.
2. What would be an ideal way to solve this? I was thinking I could signal the parent after successful execution of fork(), only after it has received the signal the parent should exit.

Comment: Are you, or your redacted _internal library_, using [`pthread_atfork` in an unsafe way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24440586/132382), and not telling us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem is related to [atfork handlers](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_atfork.3.html).

From your GDB backtrace, the parent process is doing cleanup works before process termination, which called [__unregister_atfork()](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/posix/register-atfork.c#L76).

For debug purpose,  you can attach to the child process and find out what it waits for. I expect the child process is running atfork handlers.
If you change `exit()` to `_exit()` to avoid parent cleanup, or change `fork()` to raw syscall to avoid running atfork handlers, this problem should disappear.

You may use double forks and terminate parent process after child initialization done, according to [SysV Daemon](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/daemon.html#SysV%20Daemons) requirements.

If you are sure that your program doesn't misuse `pthread_atfork()`, you can try newer compiler and glibc.

Comment: I could never deterministically recreate this problem again, it was seen on one particular machine with that particular binary of my code, with subsequent versions of binaries, never saw this. It happened in a very small time window. To prevent this from happening again, I'm terminating the parent after child has completed initialization. I'm not sure about pthread_atfork() ,I could see some calls to pthread_atfork() in the library that is used, but I'm not sure. I need to study more to understand better how things operate under the hood. Thank you for steering me in the right direction.